# Update a system file from sandboxed application

Tags: macos, swift, security, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

I am developing an app that updates the file `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist`. This file is owned by root. I have am currently updating it with the `/usr/libexec/authopen` tool, running the tool with `NSTask` and `NSPipe`. Here is the code:

```
func saveAs(fname:String) {
    // Create a dictory to write back out, and replace the knownNetworks and the preferredOrder
    let d = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary:airport_preferences)
    d[KnownNetworks] = networks
    d[PreferredOrder] = preferred_order

    let tempFileName = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "/preferences.new"
    d.writeToFile(tempFileName,atomically:true)

    let data =  NSData(contentsOfFile: tempFileName)
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/libexec/authopen"
    task.arguments = ["-c","-w",fname]
    let pipe = NSPipe()
    task.standardInput = pipe
    task.launch()
    let old_signal = signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_IGN)
    pipe.fileHandleForWriting.writeData(data!)
    pipe.fileHandleForWriting.closeFile()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    signal(SIGPIPE,old_signal)
    do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(tempFileName)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.description)
    }
}
```

To move to the App Sandbox, I am able to open the file by having the user select it in the browser. That's not hard, because I can pre-position the `NSOpenPanel`.   [Mac App Sandboxing- Updating files outside the sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815984/mac-app-sandboxing-updating-files-outside-the-sandbox) describes how to update a file outside the sandbox, but not a file owned by root.

When I run my code under sandbox, I get this error:

```
tempfile: /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist length: 339710
arguments: Optional(["-c", "-w", "/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.airport.preferences.plist"])
2015-09-26 11:46:07.699 WiFi Editor[94175:2887221] An uncaught exception was raised
2015-09-26 11:46:07.700 WiFi Editor[94175:2887221] Couldn't posix_spawn: error 1
2015-09-26 11:46:07.703 WiFi Editor[94175:2887221] (
```

(That code still has my debugging print statements in it.)

So how does one update a system file from the sandbox?

Comment: Add this as an answer and I will accept it. My plan is to display a window with text that needs to be pasted into a Terminal window. Is that allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's something that is not possible at all for an app that is sandboxed. Making the user paste text into a Terminal window isn't forbidden.